# MongoCursor.Count vs... IAsyncCursor.Count?

Tags: c#, mongodb, size

Does anybody know where is the equivalent 'Count' method of the legacy MongoCursor but in the new driver (IAsyncCursor)? Or anybody know how can I replicate this with the 2.0 Async Driver/Methods?

The idea is to get the documents queried with paging (skip & limit) and with only one database hit, get the documents, the count of that returned documents and the count of all the documents found without the LIMIT

With the MongoDB C# legacy driver I used to do this:

```
MongoCursor<SaleOrderModel> result = collection.FindAs<SaleOrderModel>(query);

result.setSkip(20);
result.setLimit(10);

var saleOrders = result.ToList<SaleOrderModel>(); // 'limited' documents
var size = result.Size(); // Count of 'limited' documents
var count = result.Count(); // Count of all documents found (even if they are not returned)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the 2.0 driver using the [`IFindFluent`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IFindFluent_2.htm) fluent query interface returned by [`Find`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Find__1.htm):

```
// Create the IFindFluent<SaleOrderModel> query.
var collection = db.GetCollection<SaleOrderModel>("saleOrders");
var filter = Builders<SaleOrderModel>.Filter.Eq(so => so.vendorId, 5);
var query = collection.Find(filter);

// Get the count of all docs matching the query.
var count = await query.CountAsync();

// Execute the query with skip and limit.
var saleOrders = await query.Skip(20).Limit(10).ToListAsync();
var size = saleOrders.Count();
```

Comment: Does what is says on the tin. It is a little different to the existing FindAsync operations. When checking system.profile I can see it has executed a query op, but I cannot see the call to mongo invoking the count. Is it possible to prove it is utilizing the same cursor?

Comment: Ah - I can see it execute a 'command' op which contains the Count instruction, but it is not associated with a cursor. I would be interested to know if it causing an index or table scan as appropriate twice, once for Count, once for Find.

Comment: Right, it's syntactically and at least _logically_ a common query, but on the server side I expect they each use independent query plans, each optimized to get just the requested data. The legacy C# approach would have done the same.